# Вывести изменяемую шахматную доску в консоли Python

Tags: python, консоль, вывод

У меня есть конь и я его хочу двигать по шахматной доске, но я не знаю как это реализовать в консоли питон, может что-то импортировать можно для такого?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/